# How to show the reject rules set by route

Tags: router

I learn the rounte command can add the reject rule by:

```
route add -host aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd reject
```

But, I have no idea to display the reject rules set. How to get the all reject rules set by others ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux at least, the `route` command shows reject-routes with a `!` in the `Flags` column, so something like:

```
route | egrep 'Flags|!'
```

will show you just the reject-routes (and the headers).

Answer (score 2):

The `ip` command can be used to show only these routes, they're called "unreachable" in `ip`.  For example:

```
$ sudo route add 8.8.8.8 reject
$ sudo ip route add unreachable 8.8.4.4
$ sudo ip route ls type unreachable
8.8.4.4 
8.8.8.8  scope host 
$
```